# How can I better handle this Flask-SQLAlchemy commit/rollback?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm reviewing some old code I wrote and was looking at a shared commit function I had written to handle responses to the user on certain failures when attempting to commit changes to the database (such as deletes):

```
def _commit_to_database():
    """A shared function to make a commit to the database and handle exceptions
    if encountered.
    """
    flask.current_app.logger.info('Committing changes to database...')
    try:
        db.session.commit()
    except AssertionError as err:
        flask.abort(409, err)
    except (exc.IntegrityError, sqlite3.IntegrityError) as err:
        flask.abort(409, err.orig)
    except Exception as err:
        flask.abort(500, err)
    finally:
        db.session.rollback()
```

I think I understand my thought process: attempt the `commit`, upon certain failures trigger a `flask.abort` to send the response back, but I believe I found that the database was left with an open session requiring a rollback when I did this and adding the `rollback` into a `finally` statement resolved this allowing me to still use the `flask.abort`.

The questions I have around me code are:

1) Is this a bug: will the Flask-SQLAlchemy extension not close out the session as normal; is calling the `rollback` on the `finally` which will be triggering after the `abort` going to affect successful `commit`s?

2) If this is a bug: what should I be doing differently in handling the `try-except-finally` and the `db` session?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to rollback when exception occurs and finally close the session:

```
def _commit_to_database(): 
    """A shared function to make a   
       commit to the database and
       handle exceptions if encountered.
    """
    flask.current_app.logger.info('Committing changes to db...')
    try: 
        db.session.commit() 
    except AssertionError as err:
        db.session.rollback()
        flask.abort(409, err) 
    except (exc.IntegrityError, sqlite3.IntegrityError) as err:
        db.session.rollback()
        flask.abort(409, err.orig) 
    except Exception as err:
        db.session.rollback()
        flask.abort(500, err) 
    finally: 
        db.session.close()
```